# how to add values to an array of objects dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is an array of objects,

```
var data = [
      {"label" : "1", "value" : 12},
      {"label" : "1", "value" : 12},
      {"label" : "1", "value" : 12},
      {"label" : "1", "value" : 12}
    ];
```

How can I add values to these dynamically? iItried the below code but no success:

```
var lab =["1","2","3", "4"];
var val = [42,55,51,22];
var data = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
   data[i].label = lab[i];
   data[i].value = val[i];    
}
```

Comment: You know that there are 3x lab and 4x val?

Comment: yes i know, its only here mistakenly.. thanks for informing me

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have to instantiate the object first. The simplest way is:

```
var lab =["1","2","3"];
var val = [42,55,51,22];
var data = [];
for(var i=0; i<4; i++)  {
    data.push({label: lab[i], value: val[i]});
}
```

Or an other, less concise way, but closer to your original code:

```
for(var i=0; i<4; i++)  {
   data[i] = {};              // creates a new object
   data[i].label = lab[i];
   data[i].value = val[i];    
}
```

`array()` will not create a new array (unless you defined that function). Either `Array()` or `new Array()` or just `[]`.

I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 12):

In Year 2019, we can use Javascript's [ES6](https://exploringjs.com/es6/) [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to do it concisely and efficiently

```
data = [...data, {"label": 2, "value": 13}]
```

**Examples**

```js
var data = [
      {"label" : "1", "value" : 12},
      {"label" : "1", "value" : 12},
      {"label" : "1", "value" : 12},
    ];
    
data = [...data, {"label" : "2", "value" : 14}] 
console.log(data)
```

For your case (i know it was in 2011), we can do it with [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like below

```js
var lab = ["1","2","3","4"];
var val = [42,55,51,22];

//Using forEach()
var data = [];
val.forEach((v,i) => 
   data= [...data, {"label": lab[i], "value":v}]
)

//Using map()
var dataMap = val.map((v,i) => 
 ({"label": lab[i], "value":v})
)

console.log('data: ', data);
console.log('dataMap : ', dataMap);
```

Comment: If in map you just make assignments, use forEach instead

Comment: I guess, i used `map` then because I didn't know the `i` can also be get in `forEach`.

Comment: I edited to include both the ways, `map()` is concise.