# How to pass a parameter from a different source into ListItem of the Flatlist?

Tags: arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist, listitem

I am rendering some items in the Flatlist where I call the renderNativeItem to render them in a ListItem and like usual I pass the values as parameter, however, I want to pass a value to subtitle from a different array.

The reason behind this is that in the ìtt parameter there are values of a users such as name, surname but in `calculated_distances` there are values calculated seperately in another function but which were fetched together from the same document in database.

So, when fetching from db, I set all the data to `this.state.dataSource` array, then I take location from that array and make a calculation and set it to `this.state.calculated_distances`. After this is done then I call Flatlist to render the `this.state.dataSource`, but the calculated distance for each user is in another array in `this.state.calculated_distances`. 
This is basically how I ended up in this situation.

Here is the `renderNativeItem` function:

```
renderNativeItem = (itt) => {
    const { calculated_distances } = this.state;
    return (
        <ListItem
            title={itt.name + " " + itt.surname}
            subtitle={calculated_distances}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: You'll have to combine your data to a single data source upon fetch.

Comment: @ChristosLytras what do you think of iman roosta's answer? Can I do it  like that?

Comment: I think there is no point doing it that way, it maybe work but yes there can be a conflict. If you combine the data, you'll know for sure which `calculated_distances` maps to each data.

Comment: @ChristosLytras but then I will have to add to that array a new field based on the calculation and I will have to do that for each object of the array. What can I use in this case?

Comment: What does `calculated_distances` do exactly? Can you share the code of `calculated_distances` and the data structure of `this.state.dataSource` `itt` item?

Comment: @ChristosLytras unfortunately I have nothing to share yet. That's why I decided to get suggestions how to do it before I start, I didn't wanna start in the wrong way. `calculated_distances` does calculate the distance between two coordinates. I get those two coordinates in `this.state.dataSource`. But I think I am gonna use the suggestions from here to implement that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858385/how-to-add-values-to-an-array-of-objects-dynamically-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. You calculate the distance values upon fetch and you update each item with a new distance property. Having to call the calculation of each item when it renders it may turn slow or laggy for the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
subtitle={functionName(itt.id)}
```

so that 
`functionName` gets `calculated_distances` with id or another value

Comment: I am sorry I think I misunderstood, what's that functionName?

Comment: functionName get parameter and map data calculated_distances any each Item